# catalog of homophones with high count of meanings

Tags: homophones

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone):

- > There are sites, for example, [this archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160825095711/http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/multinyms.html), which have lists of homonyms or rather homophones and even 'multinyms' which have as many as seven spellings.
- > In English, there are approximately 88 triples; 24 quadruples; 2 quintuples; 1 sextet and 1 septet.

Beyond the defunct page cited in the Wikipedia article, are any  references available, preferably reliable and well-maintained, that catalog examples of English homophones with particularly high counts of distinct meanings?

Comment: Probably *[lexical] **[poly]valency*** is what you're looking for.

Comment: Counting *réis* is a stretch in my opinion

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the response. Can you find any references? I am finding sources indicating a different, though not in every case very different, understanding of *valence* in the use by linguists (though many of these sources are technical and I am no linguist).

Comment: I just came up with ***valency*** because I knew that was the right term for "chemical bonds", and it would be a trivial metaphoric stretch to apply the same term to the linguistic context (discrete countable links to other atoms corresponding to countable links to other *meanings*). But whereas the numeric value of that "link number" has true significance for chemists (it has a bearing on what compounds can exist at all, and what their physical properties are) it doesn't make any real difference whether some natural language word/sound has, say, 2 or 3 potential meanings...

Comment: ...consequently there's no good reason why linguists would ever have come up with a specific word for "number of different meanings associated with a word". Also it would be very difficult in many situations to decide exactly how ***many*** "different" meanings there were (as opposed to how many different ***nuances***, etc., there might be that are all essentially just variations of a single underlying meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It may be an oversimplification, but I think a homophone generally intends to express distinct etymologies that have by chance merged into a common pronunciation in some language, or dialect. When multiple etymologies have identical spelling, then they appear in a dictionary as separate lists of items, while indeed the entries within each list may be distinct from another with such subtlety that some finite count of distinctions is impossible to resolve objectively. But you may be right that linguists never had any reason to introduce a name. I would not know.